# Wordpress Right approach in doing this signup process

Tags: wordpress, multisite

*I am not sure if I can ask this one here, but here it goes!*

I have a client who wants me to have 3 steps when a user signs up on our wordpress site.

**On the first step..**
There will be a domain availability checker. If the domain is available, they will proceed on the second step.

**On the second step..**
There will be fields such as:

- "Email Address"
- "First Name"
- "Last Name"
- A Theme/Template selection

**Third Step..**

PayPal Integration. This will be the payment page.

---

As of now, I am developing this one with the use of these plugins:

- Pro Sites
- New Blog Templates

The only problem I have or shall I say a question in my mind is that.. what is the right approach in doing this signup process?

Should I edit the wp-signup.php? Can the wp-signup.php do those steps I mentioned above?  Is that too hard to do?

Should I download a plugin that would easily modify the wp-signup look? But would those plugin work correctly with these plugins: "Pro Sites" and "New Blog Templates"?

I'm not that good in Wordpress or shall I call myself a newbie, but I think Wordpress has a lot of hacks or I just don't know what i'm talking about.

If you could provide a code or what that will be greatly appreciated!

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mess up with wp-signup.php, and you should never modify core files!

Wordpress provides a thing called `hooks`, with that you can "extend" any funcionality or make it your own taste

There are a ton of hooks you can use, like `'before_signup_form` for example.

Well, what I would do, is to use the power of **User** and **User meta** tables for storing all the content you need, since you have name and email, that's all the info you need for Wordpress to create a user, so if you want to you might take a look at these functions

```
wp_create_user();
add_user_meta();
```

Create your own page to register users.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_new_user (/wp_create_user) (/add_user_meta)

Comment: If you need any more help, post it here and I'll guide you with that

Comment: Thanks for that valuable answer. I have another question on this page, maybe you can help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191830/wordpress-multisite-add-custom-fields-on-registration-then-show-in-profile-page